# Percentage of smokers are females? Probability Question

Tags: probability

A workplace has 40% male employees. The company is concerned about the effect on health insurance premiums of the high smoking rates: 12% of employees are male smokers. Only 20% of smokers are female.
What percentage of females are smokers?

I have tried many different things to solve this and am stuck. Thanks

Comment: What things have you tried?

Comment: Making a formula for Total number of smokers, so

Comment: T = .12P + .2T, where P = number of employees

Answer (score 0):

Let the total number of employees be $x$, and the number of smokers be $s$, therefore,

1. number of male employees is $0.4x \Rightarrow$ the number of female employees is $0.6x$
2. number of male smokers is $0.12x$
3. number of female smokers is $0.2s$

Since the smokers are either male or female:
$$ 0.12x + 0.2s = s $$
$$ 0.12x = 0.8s $$
The percentage of females are smokers is:
$$ \frac{\text{# female smokers}}{\text{# females}} = \frac{0.2s}{0.6x} = 
\frac{0.25*0.8s}{0.6x} = \frac{0.25*0.12x}{0.6x} = 0.05 = 5\% $$

Comment: One mistake in your solution. HUGE error as a result. What, your answer didn't jump out at you as nowhere close to plausible? But hey, what's a hexadecimal order of magnitude error among friends?

Comment: Just found the mistake and corrected, thanks for reminding. @MarkL.Stone